# How to count the number of distinct occurrences of one row per another column value

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by

I'm looking for a way to efficiently count subvalues per ID:

```
 ID     |      subvalue
 001    |      056
 001    |      093
 001    |
 002    |      054
 002    |      033
 003    |      
 003    |      012
 003    |      094
 003    |      008
 004    |
```

To result in:

```
ID     |      Count
001    |      2
002    |      2
003    |      3
004    |      0
```

And the unique value equivalent:

Slight add:

```
  ID     |      subvalue
  001    |      001
  001    |      001
  001    |      
  002    |      002
  002    |      002
  003    |      
  003    |      003
  003    |      003
  003    |      003
  004    |
```

To result in:

```
 ID     |      Count
 001    |      2
 002    |      2
 003    |      3
 004    |      0
```

Comment: What did you try? What are the missing values, empty strings or NULLs?

Answer (score 2):

This is basic SQL, you group by the item you want and use the aggregate function count()

```
select id, count(subvalue) as count
from table
group by id
```

Count will not count nulls if you specify a field name.

If you had (not this case) empty strings (or some other criteria) that you did not want to count you could put it in the where clause or use a case, like this:

```
select id, sum(CASE stringValue = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as count
from table
group by id
```

Comment: Won't that return 1 for `004`? The OP wants to exclude the *empty* values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes I had a typo, used id instead of sub-value

Comment: @Hogan im pretty darn sure it will still return 1 for '004'

Comment: The way you are doing you need to do something like `SUM(CASE WHEN SubValue IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`

Comment: @MuhammedAli - R3ead my answer... I said clearly "**not this case**" to point out I'm generalizing my answer to other use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID VARCHAR(10), SubValue VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('001','056'),('001','093'),('001',NULL),('002','054'),
('002','033'),('003',NULL),('003','012'),('003','094'),
('003','008'),('004',NULL)

SELECT A.ID, ISNULL(COUNT(A.ID), 0) Total
FROM @T A LEFT JOIN @T B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.SubValue = B.SubValue
WHERE B.SubValue IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.ID
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║     ID  ║ Total ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║     001 ║     2 ║
║     002 ║     2 ║
║     003 ║     3 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

Or if you want to return 4 id as well you could do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, COALESCE(Total, 0) Total
FROM @T A LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS Total
                   FROM @T
                   WHERE SubValue IS NOT NULL
                   GROUP BY ID) C
ON A.ID = C.ID
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║     ID  ║ Total ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║     001 ║     2 ║
║     002 ║     2 ║
║     003 ║     3 ║
║     004 ║     0 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝

SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN SubValue IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as [COUNT]
FROM @T
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This will remove `004` from the results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Copy paste All of it in SSMS and check yourself :)

Comment: running the latest now, just taking some time

Comment: @rorytmeadows I have updated the answer try the very last one it should be a bit faster as NO joins and Distincts are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to group and exclude blanks?

Haven't run it, but I think something like this ought to get you there:

```
Select ids. ID, Coelesce(counts.value, 0)

(Select Distinct ID
 From TableName) as ids

left join

    (Select ID, Count(subvalue) as value
    From TableName
    Where value is not null 
     And value != ''
    Group By ID) as counts

on ids.id = counts.id
```